# How to Determine Device Network Name and Connectivity

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have been referencing a sample on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx that allows me to determine the network changes and the network properties, such as network name, status, etc. But how can I get this same info before a network update has occurred? For instance, when my app loads no network changes are detected so the information is currently blank. Can I force the NetworkAvailabilityChanged event to fire when the page is navigated to?

```
// Subscribe to the NetworkAvailabilityChanged event
DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new EventHandler<NetworkNotificationEventArgs>(ChangeDetected);

...


// In this callback, we examine the change that was detected. In this example, we are 
// creating a simple information string and adding that to the event list on the UI. 
// In a real application, this is where you might adjust your communication connection 
// in order to take advantage of a network availability change. 
 void ChangeDetected(object sender, NetworkNotificationEventArgs e)
{
string change = string.Empty;
switch (e.NotificationType)
{
    case NetworkNotificationType.InterfaceConnected:
        change = "Connected to ";
        break;
    case NetworkNotificationType.InterfaceDisconnected:
        change = "Disconnected from ";
        break;
    case NetworkNotificationType.CharacteristicUpdate:
        change = "Characteristics changed for ";
        break;
    default:
        change = "Unknown change with ";
        break;
}

string changeInformation = String.Format(" {0} {1} {2} ({3})",
            DateTime.Now.ToString(), change, e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceName,
            e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceType.ToString());

// We are making UI updates, so make sure these happen on the UI thread.
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    Changes.Add(changeInformation);
    UpdateNetworkStatus();
    UpdateNetworkInterfaces();

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the network information by DeviceNetworkInformation class.

you can get this DeviceNetworkInformation by adding this

"using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;"

Here the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202859%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) from Microsoft to get DeviceNetworkInformation.

Hope this helps.(correct me if i am wrong, or if its not working)

Thank you.

Comment: The `DeviceNetworkInformation` class does not return the current network name or whether an active network connection exists. I can use it to get the Cellular network and whether it is connected, but I need to gather information about the active network connection being used, wethher it be WiFi, Ethernet, Cellular, etc. I have implemented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx but I can only return the data when a network change occurs. My problem is that I also need this information as soon as the application loads and the page is navigated to.

Comment: In that link, I essentially have that same setup, except I am returning specific data about the NetworkInterface such as SubType which I cannot get using DeviceNetworkInformation directly. Correct me if I am wrong, but even when calling `UpdateNetworkInterfaces()` in the link's sample I do not return SubType data until a network change occurs and the event fires. I've tried manually firing the event handler on page load, but this is not possible either. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Mathew, you mean, if that is a cellular network, you need to know the service provider name, and if it is a wifi, u need to know the ip and all, am i right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The thing is, I believe most of the data I need can be retrieved once the `DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged` is fired, but not before. I can use DeviceNetworkInformation to get basic data like the carrier and if the cellular data connection is on, but I need specifics that are returned in `NetworkNotificationEventArgs e` when network changes occur.